# Click handler on <svg> element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, onclick, dom-events

It seems that using a `<svg:svg> </svg:svg>` element does not render anything in Safari or Chrome, but using `<svg> </svg>` works fine. However, adding an `onclick` only works on `<svg:svg>` elements. What is the proper way to do this?

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a5AN/6/) demonstrates the problem (compare Safari/Chrome to Firefox).

Comment: Why you don't use jquery to handle the events.It's easier?

Comment: Actually it works on both. But in chrome it only works if you click on  the red dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, turns out that the first way of creating a SVG creates the `onclick` only on the drawn part. That means you can actually do something nice (maybe not useful in your case).

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a5AN/9/), I created two separate `onclick`s, one that triggers when you click specifically the drawing (which i made larger so you can see) and one that triggers when you click on the SVG box, by putting a container around it.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="svgContainer">
    <svg id="firstSVG" class="s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="red"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
document.getElementById('firstSVG').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Click works here too !";  

}, false);
document.getElementById('svgContainer').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Well, a container seems better.";  

}, true);
```

So basically just use a container around the SVG, or just use the click on the drawing

Answer (score 8):

You don’t even have to put a container around the SVG.

You just need to define a `position: relative` to the SVG itself and it solve the click trigger problem.

Here’s an forked Fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/jpsirois/xnw1tbL7/

Comment: Doesn't make any difference in Safari 8.